# IF condition not working as expected in

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
for(int row=1; row <= 6; row++)
{
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get("http:/path/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String username = s.getCell(2,row).getContents();
    System.out.println("Username: "+username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_username_leftAside")).sendKeys(username);
    String password= s.getCell(3,row).getContents();
    System.out.println("Password: "+password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password_leftAside")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[@class=' js opacity generatedcontent pointerevents']/body[@class='page-homepage pageType-ContentPage template-pages-layout-RexelHomePageLayout pageLabel-homepage language-de ']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='content-top-inner']/div[@id='content-inner']/div[@class='mid-wrapper'][1]/div[@class='yCmsContentSlot']/div[@class='login clear']/form[@id='loginForm']/div[@class='left sign-in']/button[@class='Sign-in rx-btn mb0']")).click();

    if((driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div"))).isDisplayed())
    {
        System.out.println("Login Failed");
        String Error=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div")).getText();
        System.out.println("The Error mesaage is :"+Error);
        System.out.println("***********************************************************************************************************");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Login Sucessfull");
        System.out.println("***********************************");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content-inner']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[9]/a")).click();
    }
    driver.close();
}
```

IF condition is displayed print fail else pass.Its working for Fail condition but for the pass condition also its checkig and displaying unable to locate the element

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait to element to be visible:

Try this before if

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div")));
//then your code.....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot If condition will not work for isdisplayed used try catch and working fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to use try catch block like below-

```
try
{
    if((driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div"))).isDisplayed())
    {
        System.out.println("Login Failed");
        String Error=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div")).getText();
        System.out.println("The Error mesaage is :"+Error);
        System.out.println("***********************************************************************************************************");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Login Sucessfull");
    System.out.println("***********************************");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content-inner']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[9]/a")).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot working as expected